# Performance assertions

Tags: c++, c, assert, assertions

I know that C supports functional assertions using `assert()`. Is there any way/library supporting performance assertions in C/C++? Is there in any other languages?

Something along the lines of the following:

```
perf_assert_begin(ID1)
...
...
/* assert the time taken is less than 2000 ms */
perf_assert_end(ID1, interval(ID1) < 2000)
```

Comment: Well, you could start a timer, then use a normal assertion that the total is less than whatever your limit is.

Comment: Do note that `assert` is a *macro* that does nothing on typical release builds (when `NDEBUG` is defined).

Comment: Not in the language or the standard library; That said, they are (almost) trivial to write.

Comment: tick = clock(); function(); tock = clock(); assert(tock - tick < PERFORMANCE);

Comment: Please pick one language. C and C++ differ completely here.

Answer (score 1):

Assertion can be done using either `assert` from `<cassert>` or `static_assert`, which is built into the language.
So, why not take the time manually and then check the time difference in an `assert` statement?

```
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>

#ifndef NDEBUG
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
#endif
...
#ifndef NDEBUG
assert(std::chrono::duration_cast<milliseconds>(
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count() < 2000
);
#endif
```

The preprocessor directives let the code only pass through to the compiler if `NDEBUG` is defined. `assert` only takes action if `NDEBUG` is defined too and one without the other doesn't work very well.

To prevent name clashes when `NDEBUG` is defined with the `start` identifier, you might do some GCC-magic with `__COUNTER__` to make the identifier unique (compiler-specific) or move the whole thing into a separate scope. It might be a non-issue to you, but some people might be surprised by a conditionally-defined variable if they look at your program from a certain perspective.